# How can I follow new answers to a question?

Tags: feature-request, answers, community, unanswered-questions

Questions that don't yet have answers are sometimes interesting. There should be a way to get notified when answers come.

This would allow...

- knowledgeable zealots to follow questions they know something about so they can critically review incoming answers
- curious monkeys to follow questions they know nothing whatsoever about and receive delicious knowledge from incoming answers

...both of which further the goals of the site by teaching and learning, respectively.

How's that sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mark a question as a favorite (by clicking on the star on the side), then you can track activity on the question. The system is not all that robust, but it can work for this.

When you hover over your display name at the top, a table drops down that includes a row for "favorites". When a question is marked as a favorite, activity on that question (namely, new answers, comments, and revisions (but not revisions to answers!)) will increment that number. You can then click the "favorites", which will link you to the favorites section of your profile. The topmost entries should be the ones with the most recent activity - and hence you'll be able to keep track of whether or not new answers have shown up.

Comment: So the "follow" feature is called "favorite"? Good enough.